# Laravel 4 & Mandrill JSON response

Tags: json, laravel-4, mandrill

I've started sending mails through Laravel (4.2) and its embedded Mandrill driver these days, but I need to catch Mandrill's response somehow.

Here's the code I use to send the message:

```
Mail::queue('emails.customerspromo', array('messaggio'=>$content, 'disclaimer'=>$disclaimer, 'user_email'=>$to, 'user_id'=>$uid), function($message) use ($sender, $to, $subject) {
    $message->from('my@address.it', $sender);
    $message->to($to);
    $message->subject($subject);
    $message->setCharset('UTF-8');
    $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-MC-GoogleAnalytics', 'www.my-site.it');
    $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-MC-GoogleAnalyticsCampaign', 'my-campaign');
});
```

What I need to intercept is Mandrill's JSON response, for example:

```
[
    {
        "email": "destination@address.com",
        "status": "sent",
        "_id": "80e1ca49d3ed4cbb9d9a3d932c0a14f8",
        "reject_reason": null
    }
]
```

How can I do that using Laravel's integrated drivers for Mandrill?

I could use Mail::send instead of Mail::queue, if it's necessary to interpret the response in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Put a variable before your mail function like this:

```
$response = Mail::queue('emails.customerspromo', array('messaggio'=>$content, 'disclaimer'=>$disclaimer, 'user_email'=>$to, 'user_id'=>$uid), function($message) use ($sender, $to, $subject) {
    $message->from('my@address.it', $sender);
    $message->to($to);
    $message->subject($subject);
    $message->setCharset('UTF-8');
    $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-MC-GoogleAnalytics', 'www.my-site.it');
    $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-MC-GoogleAnalyticsCampaign', 'my-campaign');
});
```

It will still work but now you can see the response from mandrill.